# Spring data wth ne04j error...error while retrieving paths

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I was using spring data with neo4j.

I used `@Query` annotation to place the query in the repository, the query was as follows

```
@Query(value = "START me=node({0}), friend=node({1}) "
            + "MATCH p=shortestPath(me-[:ACTIVEFRIEND*..]->friend)"
            + " RETURN p")

public Iterable<EntityPath<User, User>> getShortestPathBetween(User a, User b);
```

In the controller I am accessing it as

```
 Iterable<EntityPath<User, User>> shortestPathBetween = this.queryService.getShortestPathBetween(user, friend);
        for (EntityPath<User, User> path : shortestPathBetween) {
            Iterator<User> iter = path.<User>nodeEntities().iterator();
        }
```

When it tries to access `path.nodeEntities`, it is causing this error:

> nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.path.ConvertingEntityPath.nodes(ConvertingEntityPath.java:137)
>   at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.path.ConvertingEntityPath.nodeEntities(ConvertingEntityPath.java:69)
>   at com.laindain.cms.controller.QueryController.getShortestPathBetween(QueryController.java:194)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

I will appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Thanks
Hemant

Answer (score 3):

Try defining the method this way:

```
public EndResult<EntityPath<User, User>> getShortestPathBetween(User a, User b);
```

since the query returns a path and not a collection of paths.
You can get the result as follows:

```
EntityPath<User, User> shortestPathBetween =
this.queryService.getShortestPathBetween(user, friend).to(EntityPath);
```

The nodes and relationships on the path can then be accessed using the *nodeEntities()* and the *relationshipEntities()* methods on the returned *EntityPath*.

Comment: Thanks remigio for the reply..Is there any other way we can do so through other return datatype...

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I'v just edited my answer, hope it will be helpful

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work. The `delegate` in `ConvertingEntityPath` is `null` because the query returns a `LinkedHashMap` and it can't be converted to a `Path.class`