# Retrieving path in Spring Data Neo4j 3.1.1 using a SpringRestGraphDatabase is not working

Tags: path, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to retrieve the shortest path between two nodes in a simple graph. I am getting a

```
NullPointerException at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.path.ConvertingEntityPath.nodes(ConvertingEntityPath.java:137)
```

Where i figured that `delegate` is null, but i don't know why.

Here is my repository with the cypher query (tested and working on neo4j UI) :

```
@Query("START from=node({0}), to=node({1}) MATCH path=(from)<-[:NETWORK_LINK*]->(to) RETURN path")
Iterable<EntityPath<DGNode, DGNode>> getShortestNetworkPathBetween(Long fromid, Long toid);
```

and my test code :

```
System.out.println("Network path from "+srv1.getId()+" to "+srv5.getId()+" :  \n");

Iterable result = nodeRepository.getShortestNetworkPathBetween(srv1.getId(), srv5.getId());

Iterable<EntityPath<DGNode,DGNode>> paths = (Iterable<EntityPath<DGNode,DGNode>>) result;
for(EntityPath<DGNode,DGNode> path : paths) {
    String nodes = "";
    while (path.nodeEntities().iterator().hasNext()) {
        nodes += ", " + ((DGNode) path.nodeEntities().iterator().next()).getName();
    }
    System.out.println("From " + path.startNode().getClass().getName() + " to " + path.endNode().getClass().getName() + " : " + nodes);
}
```

My code is based on the following example [spring-data-neo4j-examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j-examples/cineasts-aspects/src/main/java/org/neo4j/cineasts/service/FriendsMovieRecommendations.java#L50). I also checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376790/spring-data-wth-ne04j-error-error-while-retrieving-paths) but with no help: the request return a collection (QueryResultBuilder cannot be cast to EntityPath) and, by the way EndResult seems to have been renamed to Result in this version.

Comment: So, using step by step debug i found out that the query did return a result where each path found is a HashMap<String,HashMap(with each variable)> and, according to the debug, this cannot be converted to a Path, which is why ConvertingEntityPath.delegate is null. Still, i don't figure out what i'm doing wrong, should i use another return type in my repository ? If so, which one ? Thanks.

Comment: One step further! Thanks to this discution [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/Aq2jsdY41cM), this is due to the fact that i am connecting to an external Neo4j database using SpringRestGraphDatabase. When using an embedded one, the issue is gone and i have my paths... Anyone knows how to fix this ?

Comment: use Iterable<String,Path> as return type